# Constructor Injection into an Abstract or Parent Class

Tags: java, dependency-injection, abstract-class, parent, constructor-injection

Me and another developer have recently forked and taken over an abandoned, open-source project. I have also been reading articles and watching videos by Misko Hevery:

http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEhu57pih5w&list=PLD0011D00849E1B79

So when I was reading thru the projects code, I noticed a lot of no-argument constructors. And that the fields are being assigned via static calls instead of being assigned via the constructor parameters. When I saw this, I wanted to refactor the constructors to declare their dependencies explicitly.

This is simple to do.

However, the problem is that there are parent classes (some abstract) with fields that need to be initialized. So what is the best way to do DI for parent classes ?

I mean, the child class can ask for parameters (that it doesn't really need) in its constructor... only to pass it to the parent via super(arg1, arg2);

But this seems really bizarre to me: That the child is asking for something just to pass it to the parent. Is this really the way it's supposed to be done ?

What about an abstract constructor (with necessary parameters) that forces the child to implement ?

Comment: It is not uncommon for that to happen.  The Extended Class is what it is extending.  So therefore the Extended Class has to implement all the behavior its parent does and if the parent needs to call other classes to do its work, then the Extending Class has to provided those classes to the parent.